# update val input unchanged on first hit, works on next hit

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just modified simple dinamically onChange code and added some input text below select option. theres 3 input text under it, soon after finished some modification im try it running. then **why 3rd input text unchanged** on first hit, it work only on next hit. 
let say we pick a date : 17/08/1945 (datepicker inputtext)
1rst inputfield show only name of day :Friday
2nd inputfield returning value month  : August
3rd inputfield date written in words  : seventeen august one thousand nine hundred and forty-five
i know that doesn't sound like a very useful way to display a date in english, but here in Indonesia, writing the date in a word usually used for credit agreements or agreements handover and required by law
I'm making a small application and on a menu provides a feature to print a letter of agreement, automatically. that's why I need a date written in words.
snippet and jsfiddle been replaced using the international language.

```js
$( function() {
$( "#pickyDate" ).datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});
daylocal = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu' ];
monthlocal = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktober','November','Desember' ];

 

$('#pickyDate').datepicker()
.on("change", function () {    

 var today = new Date($('#pickyDate').datepicker('getDate'));
 var date = today.getDate();
 var daysnumber = today.getDay();
 var monthnumber = today.getMonth(); 
 var years = today.getFullYear(); 
     

 numbers    = $('#dateinword').val();
 var number   = new Array('0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0');
 var words    = new Array('','Satu','Dua','Tiga','Empat','Lima','Enam','Tujuh','Delapan','Sembilan');/*1 to 9 */
 var level = new Array('','Ribu','Juta','Milyar','Triliun'); /*hundred,thousand,billion,trillion */
 
 var length_numbers = numbers.length;
 
 /* long test numbers */
 if (length_numbers > 15) {
   sentences = "Out of Limit";
   return sentences;
 }
 
 /* get numbers set to array */
 for (i = 1; i <= length_numbers; i++) {
   number[i] = numbers.substr(-(i),1);
 }
 
 i = 1;
 j = 0;
 sentences = "";
 
 
 /* iteration array number */
 while (i <= length_numbers) {
 
   subsentences = "";
   words1 = "";
   words2 = "";
   words3 = "";
 
   /* hundred */
   if (number[i+2] != "0") {
     if (number[i+2] == "1") {
       words1 = "Seratus";     /*Seratus mean One hundred */
     } else {
       words1 = words[number[i+2]] + " Ratus";  /* Ratus mean hundred  */
     }
   }
 
   /* tens or dozen */
   if (number[i+1] != "0") {
     if (number[i+1] == "1") {
       if (number[i] == "0") {
         words2 = "Sepuluh";   /* sepuluh mean ten */ 
       } else if (number[i] == "1") {
         words2 = "Sebelas";  /* sebelas mean eleven */
       } else {
         words2 = words[number[i]] + " Belas"; /* >10 - 19 using suffix Belas */
       }
     } else {
       words2 = words[number[i+1]] + " Puluh"; /* puluh is suffix like ty in english [20,30,40,...90]   */
     }
   }
 
   /* single number */
   if (number[i] != "0") {
     if (number[i+1] != "1") {
       words3 = words[number[i]];
     }
   }
 
   /* zero cheking, add level */
   if ((number[i] != "0") || (number[i+1] != "0") || (number[i+2] != "0")) {
     subsentences = words1+" "+words2+" "+words3+" "+level[j]+" ";
   }
 
   /* join var sentences (as one blok 3 digit 000) into var sentences */
   sentences = subsentences + sentences;
   i = i + 3;
   j = j + 1;
 
 }
 
 /* replace Satu Ribu(one thousand) will be Seribu if needed */
 if ((number[5] == "0") && (number[6] == "0")) {
   sentences = sentences.replace("Satu Ribu","Seribu"); /* Ribu = thousand we use prefix se for one  */
 }
 
 //return sentences;

   //alert(local[today.getDay()]);
   //alert(kalimat);
   $('#daypk').val(daylocal[today.getDay()]);
   $('#dateinword').val(date);
   $('#worddate').val(sentences);

//document.getElementById("terbilang").innerHTML=kalimat;



});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        
        <div class="col-lg-3">

   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="specify the date of the loan agreement" name="pickyDate" id="pickyDate" />
   </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name of the day" name="daypk" id="daypk" disabled/>
    </div>

             <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dateinword" name="dateinword" id="dateinword" disabled/>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="will be dd/mm/yy in word" name="worddate" id="worddate" disabled/> 
             </div>


  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ariowishnu/vLeqLkj6/1/

Comment: Don't use language other than English for your code. The posted one is almost impossible to follow.

Comment: @LGSon:Can you explain just the algorithm, why such a thing could happen

Comment: It can be anything from a misspelled variable/function to a logic error...so it is pretty much impossible to say

Comment: Google translate thinks this is Indonesian.

Comment: Hi gyre..yups im indonesian , maybe u can help me to slve little problem here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can say that I don't speak Indonesian, and so it's difficult to tell what exactly your code intends to do and why your logic might be structured the way it is. However, I might be able to give you a few pointers based on my testing of your code that might change the results for the first `change` event:

- You set some variable `bilangan = $('#nominal').val()` towards the beginning of your event handler. This will always be the empty string `''` on the first iteration, because nothing has been inputted into that field yet.
- You base your `while` loop off of a variable `panjang_bilangan = bilangan.length`. That loop will never run the first time, because `bilangan` is the empty string and thus has a length of zero.
- Your third input (the one that is having the error) seems to be updated entirely based off of a variable called `kaLimat`. From what I can tell, the only places where this variable is updated to include some meaningful value are inside your `while` loop, and that is why for the first event `kaLimat` ends up being empty, and your `<input id="terbilang">` doesn't change.

---

**Edit: I think I found a solution**

The problem was with `numbers = $('#dateinwords').val()`. That line should be:

```
var numbers = date + ''
```

...which sets numbers to the string-equivalent of the selected day of the month ("date").

I also prefixed a few of your variables with `var` when you set them initially so that they don't leak into the global namespace.

I did not take a look at the correctness of your algorithm to turn dates into strings, since I don't fully understand the rules by which that should be done in Indonesian. Let me know if the snippet doesn't function as intended.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  daylocal = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu'];
  monthlocal = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember'];



  $('#pickyDate').datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' })
    .on("change", function() {

      var today = new Date($('#pickyDate').datepicker('getDate'));
      var date = today.getDate();
      var daysnumber = today.getDay();
      var monthnumber = today.getMonth();
      var years = today.getFullYear();


      var numbers = date + ''
      var number = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'];
      var words = new Array('', 'Satu', 'Dua', 'Tiga', 'Empat', 'Lima', 'Enam', 'Tujuh', 'Delapan', 'Sembilan'); /*1 to 9 */
      var level = new Array('', 'Ribu', 'Juta', 'Milyar', 'Triliun'); /*hundred,thousand,billion,trillion */

      var length_numbers = numbers.length;

      /* long test numbers */
      if (length_numbers > 15) {
        var sentences = "Out of Limit";
        return sentences;
      }

      /* get numbers set to array */
      for (i = 1; i <= length_numbers; i++) {
        number[i] = numbers.substr(-(i), 1);
      }

      i = 1;
      j = 0;
      sentences = "";


      /* iteration array number */
      while (i <= length_numbers) {

        var subsentences = "";
        words1 = "";
        words2 = "";
        words3 = "";

        /* hundred */
        if (number[i + 2] != "0") {
          if (number[i + 2] == "1") {
            words1 = "Seratus"; /*Seratus mean One hundred */
          } else {
            words1 = words[number[i + 2]] + " Ratus"; /* Ratus mean hundred  */
          }
        }

        /* tens or dozen */
        if (number[i + 1] != "0") {
          if (number[i + 1] == "1") {
            if (number[i] == "0") {
              words2 = "Sepuluh"; /* sepuluh mean ten */
            } else if (number[i] == "1") {
              words2 = "Sebelas"; /* sebelas mean eleven */
            } else {
              words2 = words[number[i]] + " Belas"; /* >10 - 19 using suffix Belas */
            }
          } else {
            words2 = words[number[i + 1]] + " Puluh"; /* puluh is suffix like ty in english [20,30,40,...90]   */
          }
        }

        /* single number */
        if (number[i] != "0") {
          if (number[i + 1] != "1") {
            words3 = words[number[i]];
          }
        }

        /* zero cheking, add level */
        if ((number[i] != "0") || (number[i + 1] != "0") || (number[i + 2] != "0")) {
          subsentences = words1 + " " + words2 + " " + words3 + " " + level[j] + " ";
        }

        /* join var sentences (as one blok 3 digit 000) into var sentences */
        sentences = subsentences + sentences;
        i = i + 3;
        j = j + 1;

      }

      /* replace Satu Ribu(one thousand) will be Seribu if needed */
      if ((number[5] == "0") && (number[6] == "0")) {
        sentences = sentences.replace("Satu Ribu", "Seribu"); /* Ribu = thousand we use prefix se for one  */
      }

      //return sentences;

      //alert(local[today.getDay()]);
      //alert(kalimat);
      $('#daypk').val(daylocal[today.getDay()]);
      $('#dateinword').val(date);
      $('#worddate').val(sentences);

      //document.getElementById("terbilang").innerHTML=kalimat;



    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <div class="col-lg-3">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="specify the date of the loan agreement" name="pickyDate" id="pickyDate" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name of the day" name="daypk" id="daypk" disabled/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dateinword" name="dateinword" id="dateinword" disabled/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="will be dd/mm/yy in word" name="worddate" id="worddate" disabled/>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi gyre, ure rockk, thanks , i dont realize that var bilangan ( means number in english) is always empty for the first run because textfield  related to that var is ' '.  I think thats the point . Maybe any suggestion or other way how to set the code working might be any other event that fit to this case. How bout changedate or onselect ?

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question and explain to us a little bit more about what your algorithm is supposed to do? Like what the three inputs are supposed to mean, and some examples for what you'd like them to say? I am mostly confused why you are accessing `bilangan = $('#nominal').val()` at all, because this will always refer to information from the **previous** date that was inputted. That could be intentional, but I can't be sure without a little more context.

Comment: questions have added information, so it is easy to understand

Comment: Just checking to make sure you saw that I edited my post. Does it work OK?

Comment: hy gyre..., i just can tell its worked. amazing, oh god. believe me. universe need more people like u ...,btw im trying to give upvote but why  arrow doesnt change at all ? on behalf of the people of Indonesia, once again say thank you, for your time and thoughts you have given. :)

Comment: hy gyre , I recently realized that I needed `var_years` to be converted too, is it possible if we add some extra var e.g : `var years = year + ''` side by side with  `var numbers = date + ''`, so later i'll join all part of dates with concatenation string.